# Output a series of images from a db into a variable?

Tags: php, while-loop, mysqli

I have a number of images in my db and they all correspond to the same project ID.

I want them to be displayed next to each other in the browser.

But the following code is output only the latest image but not all of them:

```
//get all the images in this project and add them to the content variable for output

                if (!empty($FormProjectID)) {

                    $DBQuery3 = mysqli_query($dblink, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE project_id = '$FormProjectID'");

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($DBQuery3) < 1) {
                        $content = '
                            <p>This project is empty. <a href="index.php?page=upload&id='.$FormProjectID.'">Upload</a> some files to get started.</p>
                        ';
                    } else {

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($DBQuery3)) {
                            $DBImageID = $row['image_id'];
                            $DBProjectID = $row['project_id'];
                            $DBImageName = $row['image_name'];
                            $DBImageDescription = $row['image_description'];
                            $DBDateCreated = $row['date_created'];
                            $DBLinkToFile = $row['link_to_file'];
                            $DBGivenName = $row['given_name'];

                            //if the image was given a name by the user, display it
                            //otherwise display the generated name

                            if (strlen($DBGivenName) > 1) {
                                $FileName = $DBGivenName;
                            } else {
                                $FileName = $DBImageName;
                            }

                            $content = '
                                <div class="image">
                                <a href="index.php?page=image&id='.$DBImageID.'"><img src="'.$DBLinkToFile.'" alt="'.$FileName.'" title="'.$FileName.'"/></a>
                                </div>
                            ';
                    }
                }
```

How do I get all the image so that in the end the html looks like this:

```
<div class="image">
                                <a href="index.php?page=image&id='.$DBImageID.'"><img src="'.$DBLinkToFile.'" alt="'.$FileName.'" title="'.$FileName.'"/></a>
                                </div>
<div class="image">
                                <a href="index.php?page=image&id='.$DBImageID.'"><img src="'.$DBLinkToFile.'" alt="'.$FileName.'" title="'.$FileName.'"/></a>
                                </div>
<div class="image">
                                <a href="index.php?page=image&id='.$DBImageID.'"><img src="'.$DBLinkToFile.'" alt="'.$FileName.'" title="'.$FileName.'"/></a>
                                </div>
```

Later on in my html page I have:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$content = '` to `$content .= '`

[PHP String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Note: set the  `$content` variable to empty string or null  before your while loop

Comment: +1 - as a rule of thumb if only the last item of a loop is shown in code, there's a good chance that it's a concatenation problem.

Comment: Thanks so much to the both of you. That was it, working nicely now. I thought it had something to do with this but was too worried that I would mess up my code. No risk, no gain I guess.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is string concatenation (see [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php))

to fix your problem you'll need to first initialise an empty string, do this before your while loop

```
} else {
    $content = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($DBQuery3)) {
```

and then use the concatenation operator `.` to append each image

```
    $content .= '
        <div class="image">
        <a href="index.php?page=image&id='.$DBImageID.'"><img src="'.$DBLinkToFile.'" alt="'.$FileName.'" title="'.$FileName.'"/></a>
        </div>
    ';
```